# Can I put Open Graph tags out of the head tag of my page?

Tags: seo, facebook-opengraph

I am talking about the Open Graph tag here. Can I put the og meta tag anywhere on the page?

I want to use my detail page image for the og tag, the easiest solution is putting the og:image tag in the body of my page.

Answer (score 1):

Open Graph meta tags should *always* be nested between `<head>` tags.

> To turn your web pages into graph objects, you need to add basic
>   metadata to your page. We've based the initial version of the protocol
>   on RDFa which means that you'll place additional `<meta>` tags in the
>   `<head>` of your web page.
>
> http://ogp.me/#metadata

Additionally, keep in mind that order of the tags matters, especially when dealing with [array](http://ogp.me/#array) tags (which includes og:image).

Answer (score -3):

Open Graph Tag should be always always be placed on header tag until knowledge goes.. People please correct me if I am wrong..

Comment: Please provide supporting sources or additional information to your answer in the future. Currently, your answer reads more like another question than an answer.

Comment: Generally meta tags can be placed anywhere on the page. When I check my page preview on facebook it just works fine but on some pages unfortunately this doesn’t work. I tried different URLs in case social media cache can cause any issue. Other than that are there any SEO rule saying og tags must be in head tags. Please provide resources.